# Need suggestion for Smart target promotion edit within XPM

Tags: experience-manager, smarttarget

I have Smart target functional with XPM editable where Editor can edit the current promtions showing on the page.

I have to update the fallback component, promotions for current trigger and all promotions available on that page or all the promotions of a smart target regions available on the page. Can anyone suggest the best way to implement this functionality.

I can understand that I can update my promotions using footprint for each type of trigger, but I want to know how I can update all the promotions for a particular region ignoring trigger type and how can I update the fallback component.